# simple implementation leaky integrator in python

Tags: python, iteration

I want to implement a simple leaky fire integrator model in Python. The idea is to apply a formula to compute the voltage (u) over a window of time, and reset the voltage to 0 when a certain time is reached (in my code, when t reaches t_btw_spikes). Here my code:

```
# Leaky Integrator   

def leaky_int(R, I_c, t, tau):
    t_btw_spikes = tau*np.log((R*I_c)/R*I_c-v_th)
    while t < t_btw_spikes:
        u = (R*I_c*(1-np.exp(-t_array/tau)))
        t +=0.001
    else:
        u = 0
```

And here is how I call this function

```
t = 0
R = 1
v_th = 15
t_array = np.linspace(0,0.1, 1000)
tau = 0.01 #s
I_c = 20
trial1 = leaky_int(R, I_c, t, tau)
plt.plot(t_array, trial1)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Voltage')
#check time btw spikes
t_btw_spikes = tau*np.log((R*I_c)/R*I_c-v_th)
print(t_btw_spikes)
```

The problem is that it returns

> ValueError: x and y must not be None

Comment: It doesn't look like your function returns anything. So the variable trial1 does not contain any values.

Comment: You need to indicate where the error happens. It will help you to find a solution yourself.

Comment: You also need to figure out what it is you are trying to do.